# Searching words in PDF and Extracting it using iText in android

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

I recently downloaded iText 5.3.3 and i'm having a bit of a trouble using it.

**What classes do i use to Search Words and Extract them from the PDF and display the text in Android?**

I have seen the class **PdfTextExtractor**, i want to know in the class there is a method with a parameter of `TextExtractionStrategy strategy`. what TextExtractionStrategy  are they referring to?

```
    public static String getTextFromPage(PdfReader reader,
                                 int pageNumber,
                                 TextExtractionStrategy strategy)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check these links for it, it also tell you about `TextExtractionStrategy` (last link):

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=275
http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=277
http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=278
http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/TextExtractionStrategy.html