# Reading hidden content from a pdf in java

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox

I have several pdfs with some codes scatterred across (no fixed position) as below:

```
oneCode=abcd
twoCode=4566
```

Also, the font color of the text is white (same as the background color of the PDF). So they are invisible to eye.

I want to write a program to parse the pdf using the keys (first part of the complete word e.g. oneCode, twoCode, etc.) and get the corresponding values (e.g. abcd, 4566, etc.).

Is such a functionality available in any open source pdf parsers like PDFBox, iText, etc. ?

Can any one please point to a example ?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Both PDFBox and iText have text parsing capabilities but these capabilities obviously are not specialized for your use case. Have a look at the [ExtractPageContent* samples here](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=15) for iText and [ExtractTextByArea.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/ExtractTextByArea.java) and other classes using the `PDFTextStripper` for PDFBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938397/searching-words-in-pdf-and-extracting-it-using-itext-in-android) will help you out.

Up to Version 2.1.7 iText is open-source and free for commercial use. Please make sure the methods you need are available in Version 2.1.7 and below.
Otherwise you can get the latest version from [source-forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/). But be aware that their licensing is obscure and they deleted the old versions from source-forge.

Comment: iText is AGPL: it is still free, and for sure it's still open source. You might want to correct your statement.

Comment: Are you sure? Cause I did some research for a commercial product. See http://itextpdf.com/pricing/desktop_license. From what I can see the license is unclear. Check the comments under http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/

Comment: iText offers two main licensing models: You can either use it according to the AGPL (no need to buy a license, but your program using it also must be open source, at least for its users, *users* being interpreted in an extensive ways, for details look up the AGPL) or commercially (buy a license, but your program may remain closed source).

Comment: iText actually has [a dual license](http://itextpdf.com/pricing): either AGPL (and that one is free of use) or commercial (for a fee, and that will release you from the AGPL terms). As for removing old releases, there's no reason to keep them : they are buggy, lack features, and potentially have legal issues (see this [blog post](http://lowagie.com/iText2)).