# itext - Fastest way to extract text from pdf

Tags: java, android, itext

I'm trying to extract text from pdf files in Android, about 30 pages long, using examples from this post:

[Searching words in PDF and Extracting it using iText in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938397/searching-words-in-pdf-and-extracting-it-using-itext-in-android)

My problem is that it takes too long to extract the text, about 10 seconds so I was wondering if there is a faster method for extracting the text.

I actually need to search inside the pdf, and I didn't find a way to do this, without extracting the text first.

Comment: you can do both the task simultaneously using Threading. If you are able to calculate no of characters in the pdf before extracting, then you can easily run a search thread and dont stop it until you have read searched in all the characters.

Comment: At least you do not need to extract all Text. Instead you can extract page By page and search the content of each page right after it is extracted. This way it takes that long only if the text is not found.

Comment: Furthermore you can try using a non-standard text extraction strategy.  The location Text extraction strategy can take longer than e.g. The simple text extraction strategy.

Comment: I thought of searching for the string and stop extraction when the string is found, but it is not enough, that means there are still 5-6 seconds needed to search. Also, I don't think that's scalable, i.e. i won't be able to do some complex searches...